# In low voltage (3-12V) DC applications, which is safer to be exposed or touchable + or - terminal?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, electrons

The - side has a surplus of $e^{-}$s and the opposite is true for the + side of the power supply.  Does it not matter, or depends on your configuration / contact with Earth? Please explain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safety of a low voltage DC power supply is not established by the voltage on its output, but by the isolation between its input and output terminals. For example, a defective 12V power supply may have a short between the 120V AC input terminal and its negative output terminal. A user who would be connected to ground would then experience a 120V AC voltage at the negative output terminal and a 120V AC voltage overlaid by a 12V DC voltage at the positive terminal. The danger comes in both cases from the 120V AC component. Touching either terminal would be unsafe and both voltages could be potentially fatal.

In practice these kinds of faults are very rare because of the safety requirements for these power supplies. What does happen, however, is that there is an effective capacitance between the input and the output of the supply. This is principally unavoidable and it does lead to an AC current flowing from either output terminal to ground. There are different limits for this current, depending on the application and safety class of the power supply. For a medical grade supply, this current has to be limited according to IEC60601-1 to 0.3mA. This is reasonable rating to prevent serious electric shock, but you could definitely feel it in some sensitive areas with wet skin. Any medical equipment using such a supply that connects directly to a patient trough any sort of conductor (e.g. ECG machines) is therefor required to further limit this current to a much lower limit trough any terminal of the machine that patients and users can come in contact with.

Answer (score 1):

Low voltage sources don't have enough potential to conduct through your skin or body so touching either the positive or negative doesn't make a difference.  For you to feel it or get tissue damage, current must flow through you.  This won't happen with very low voltage sources unless you're covered with something more conductive like wet salt water.  But 12V is so low even covered with salt water you might not get any current to conduct.